# Flutter - How to have A Dynamic Home Page by using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am new to Flutter and Firebase and am working on an authentication app.
How do I make the app go to the HomePage if a user is signed in already or go to the login page if no user is signed in?
Forgive my rusty code.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.instance;
void main() {

  Future<bool> home() async {
    if (await auth.currentUser() == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      title: 'DASH',
      home: home() == null ? LoginScreen() : HomeScreen(),
      theme: DashTheme.theme,
      color: DashTheme.white,
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      // Set routes for using the Navigator.
       '/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomeScreen(),
       '/login': (BuildContext context) => new LoginScreen(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Future Builder

```
 Widget _getLandingPage() {
return FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
  future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot){
    if (GlobalStore.state.userConfig != null && GlobalStore.state.userConfig.isDisplayIntroScreen == true) {
      return routes.buildPage('intro_screen', null);
    }

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return routes.buildPage('main', null);
    } else {
      return routes.buildPage('auth', null);
    }
  },);

home: _getLandingPage(),
```

Answer (score 0):

While I never wrote anything in the `Dart` language, I can see that you wrote some good beginning. If we take a look at this line:

```
home: home() == null ? LoginScreen() : HomeScreen(),
```

You are checking in `home()` if the user is logged in. However, you are checking if the return value is `null` while the returned object of the method is `Future<bool>`. (This means that in this case the condition is always `false`).

Also note that this method is `async`. That means that you will not really know when this method is actually done executing. (This will be some moment in the ***future***).

That being said, you should display an initial page once the app starts up. Then you should run and check the return value of the future method. According to the docs (https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures) this can be done like this:

```
// Call this after the initialization of your app and pages

final future = home();
future.then((isLoggedIn) => ); // Inside here you need to do a navigation to the homepage or loginpage
```

Comment: `bool isLoggedIn;`
 `final future = home();`
 `future.then((isLoggedIn) => false);`
 `home: isLoggedIn ? HomeScreen() : LandingScreen(),`

Answer (score 0):

A little modification is required in your code.

Instead of checking the current user in the main function like that, what you can do is check user in the **initState()** function.

```
@override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();

    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    if(_auth.currentUser() == null)
    {
       Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/LoginScreen" , (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    }
    else
    {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil("/HomeScreen" , (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    }

  }
```

**pushNamedAndRemoveUntil** is used if you don't want the user to go back to the previous scene or route.

You can Read about Navigation in flutter [here](http://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html). And use the one you need.

Comment: Thank you. Now how do I pass that to the home of the Material App widget?

Comment: Well what I will recommend is don't pass dynamic screen to **Home** instead you can use a simple loading screen as home or even a splash screen and do the checking part in that . Later when you know the result(if user is new or not) then you can route to new screen based on the result. Because home is generally the screen which user will when he first enters so a simple loading screen or splash screen will be good. I hope you got my point : )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for all your answers.
I was checking up on the answers and this is what I came across. 
I don't know if it's the right thing to do but it is actually working. 
Here is the code:

---

```
Widget _getLandingPage() {
return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data.providerData.length == 1) {
        return snapshot.data.isEmailVerified ? HomeScreen() : VerifyEmailScreen();
      } else {
        return HomeScreen();
      }
    } else {
      return LoginScreen();
    }
  },
);
```

}

```
home: _getLandingPage(),
```